# What's the least impacting virtualization software to run on Windows 11?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-11, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I'm exploring options for running a Windows virtual machine on Windows 11 (32gb ram, i7 1265u), while also utilizing WSL2. Between VMware Workstation 17 ([now able to run along Hyper-V](https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html)) and the built-in Hyper-V, I'm interested in understanding which option would be less intrusive to my computer's overall usage experience and offer better performance, without considering the cost factor.
As an example, does Hyper V require complex network configurations? Does VmWare workstation impact on WSL?

Comment: Would you consider Cygwin? No virtualisation at all

Comment: Don't overthink. I have two equal machines:  1 a Hyper-V / WSL machine and 1 a VMware Workstation Pro machine. These are the 2 best. Neither hampers the host machine. Guests are fast. Pick what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using WSL2 then you depend on Windows Hypervisor Platform and your choices are limited to software that can also run on WHP. This includes Hyper-V (of course; WSL2 is practically Hyper-V) as well as QEMU and VirtualBox, both of which support WHP as a backend. Probably others, but as far as I know it *doesn't* include VMware Workstation, which requires using its own hypervisor and therefore cannot be used together with WHP.

Out of those three, Hyper-V would be the least intrusive because you already have half of it; e.g. the virtual network interface that connects Windows to the Linux VMs is *literally* a hidden Hyper-V Virtual Switch (with an additional NAT feature).

However, VirtualBox might offer better choices for emulated hardware (and things like USB passthrough). It does require its own driver for most networking modes, but that doesn't conflict with the rest.

You can have VirtualBox installed together with WSL2 and Hyper-V and it'll automatically switch to WHP mode when its own hypervisor driver is not available. Its WHP support isn't *quite* as good as its own hypervisor (certain things can be slow), but it should do the job.

QEMU is popular elsewhere (together with the Linux KVM hypervisor it's the most commonly used combination for server hosting), but lacks good management tools (i.e. it's not really a *user-friendly* option). It doesn't actually have its own hypervisor at all; it's always paired with KVM or WHP or something like that. I'm not sure how it handles networking on Windows (other than "VirtualBox NAT"-style userspace networking).

As far as I know, VMWare Workstation (at least the version I tried ~12 months ago) does not support running on any other hypervisor except its own, which is understandable, but it does prevent WSL2 usage (as there can't be two active hypervisors on the same system).

None of them really affect computer performance much, as all rely on your CPU's hardware-virtualization support for the heavy lifting when a VM is running (the software only handles things like storage and device emulation), and there is zero effect when no VMs are running.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the fact that now VmWare Workstation can run with WSL2, hence my question.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there is much of a difference whatsoever? They're all on the same level if they all use WHP.